# how to wait for a value and add it to list flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, asynchronous, async-await

I have this piece of code

```
Future<List<RoomModel>> getTeacherRooms(String email) async {
    var docs = await _roomRepo.getTeacherRooms(email);
    List<RoomModel> rooms = [];
    docs.map((doc) async {
      var room = await toRoom(doc);
      rooms.add(room);
    }).toList();
    return rooms;
}
```

I need to wait for `toRoom()` to return a value then put it in rooms
the problem is with this code is that rooms is returned empty

Comment: see `Future.wait` or `Future.forEsch` methods

Comment: still not working.

Comment: the same issue.

Comment: `final rooms = await Future.wait(docs.map(toRoom)); print(rooms);`

Comment: the problem with that is that the type of rooms is ganna be List<Future<RoomModel>>

Comment: no: `List<RoomModel>` - i assume `toRoom` method returns `Future<RoomModel>`

Answer (score 0):

I just used "pskink" answer to solve this problem
this is the code

```
Future<List<RoomModel>> getTeacherRooms(String email) async {
         var docs = await _roomRepo.getTeacherRooms(email);
         return await Future.wait(docs.map((doc) => toRoom(doc)).toList());
}
```

Comment: actually in this case you just need `return await Future.wait(docs.map(toRoom));` - no need for anonymous closure for `map` method and extra  `toList` (`Future.wait` needs `Iterable`, not `List`)